# Editing a file based on a pattern appearance

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file that contains text and numbers like this:

```
state(1, s(1,a), [s(1,b)]).
state(1, s(1,b), [s(1,a)]).
state(1, s(2,a), [s(2,b)]).
state(1, s(2,b), [s(2,a)]).
state(1, s(3,a), [s(3,b)]).
state(1, s(3,b), [s(3,a)]).
state(1, s(4,a), [t(1), t(2)]).
state(1, s(5,a), [t(1), t(3)]).
state(1, s(6,a), [s(6,b)]).
state(1, s(6,b), [s(6,a)]).
...so on
```

I want the numbering with in s(x,y) to change as follows:

```
state(1, p(1), 0, [p(2)]).
state(1, p(2), 0, [p(1)]).
state(1, p(3), 0, [p(4)]).
state(1, p(4), 0, [p(3)]).
state(1, p(5), 0, [p(6)]).
state(1, p(6), 0, [p(5)]).
state(1, p(7), -1, [t(1), t(2)]).
state(1, p(8), -1, [t(1), t(3)]).
state(1, p(9), 0, [p(10)]).
state(1, p(10), 0, [p(9)]).
...so on
```

The 0 and -1 in the third argument in the state are just to suggest that there was/is an s-s (or p-p) connection(represented as 0), or not (represented as -1).

I tried "sed", but I was not at all near successful.

Can I get some hints or solutions?

Comment: How are the numbers in the last column created?

Comment: @Cyrus The goal is to renumber the states in the whole file. The mapping from s(i,a) or s(i,b) to a p(j) should be consistent.

Comment: You need to do numerical processing also, not only pattern matching, use awk or any other programming language, to write a script for your requirements.

Comment: @thanasisp can you please check the answer that I posted just now? Seems to be working. Please upvote the answer, if you find that to be correct.

Answer (score 4):

[Using the right tool for text-processing rather than a shell loop](/q/169716/72456):

```
gawk -F'(,[[:blank:]]+\\[?|\\]\\)\\.)' '!twice{ seen[$2]=NR; next } {
    print $1, "p(" FNR ")", (($3 in seen)?"0, [p("seen[$3]")":"-1, ["$3", "$4)"]).";
}' OFS=', ' infile twice=1 infile
```

We defined field seperator to sets of `,<one-or-more-whitespaces><with-optional-]>` or `]).`

We are processing input file `infile` twice, so first we read the second field based on FS we set above and add them into an associated `seen` named array; the keys for this array is second field content and the value is NR for each (`NR` in awk represent the **N**umber of **R**ecord for the input(s), `FNR` is the same but that reset for each next input file); this cycle repeat until all lines read and finished. variable `twice=1` and condition `!twice` are used to force awk to run the first block only once and for the first time we process the input file only.

In the `print` line, that is for run and processing the input file for the second time; we print first field, then `p(#)` (where `#`s reproduce by FNR); then we check the third field against the all keys in array `seen`, if match found in the array the we print `0, [p(#)]).` (where `#` is the position number of the matched key's value was seen in the array) else print `-1, [...]).`

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the input file as "sample.txt"

We first need to put the 0 and -1 bits to the file:

```
cat sample.txt | sed 's/, \[s/, 0, \[s/g' | sed 's/, \[t/, -1, \[t/g' > sample1.txt
```

Once we have the new "sample1.txt" file, we can run the following bash script (convert.bash).

```
#!/bin/bash

k=0
maxstates=$(wc -l "$1" | gawk '{print $1}')

for i in $(seq 1 "$maxstates")
do
    count=$(grep -c "s($i,a)" "$1")
    if [ "$count" -ne 0 ]
    then
        k=$((k + 1))
        sed -i "s/s($i,a)/p($k)/g" "$1"
    fi
    count=$(grep -c "s($i,b)" "$1")
    if [ "$count" -ne 0 ]
    then
        k=$((k + 1))
        sed -i "s/s($i,b)/p($k)/g" "$1"
    fi
done
```

Now, to run the file:

```
bash convert.bash sample1.txt
```

It edits sample1.txt in place and the new content is:

```
state(1, p(1), 0, [p(2)]).
state(1, p(2), 0, [p(1)]).
state(1, p(3), 0, [p(4)]).
state(1, p(4), 0, [p(3)]).
state(1, p(5), 0, [p(6)]).
state(1, p(6), 0, [p(5)]).
state(1, p(7), -1, [t(1), t(2)]).
state(1, p(8), -1, [t(1), t(3)]).
state(1, p(9), 0, [p(10)]).
state(1, p(10), 0, [p(9)]).
```

Comment: Regardless if it is doing or not what your requirements say (I haven't test that), this is a shell loop, and for every iteration, there are many processes executed (grep, seds etc). This practice is strongly discouraged, the shell is a language to manage a system, to call and connect commands to each other, not a usual programming language. It will be very inefficient in terms of perfomance. You have to encapsulate your logic into one script, one program, and run one process and execute it once for the whole file. `awk` fits to this task, languages like Perl, Python also.

Comment: @thanasisp yes I agree, there is an issue with efficiency. Since there are not many states (maybe 100-1000) in my present problem, I think it is okay to use this script.

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http:shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Comment: You are parsing the same file 4,000 times.